# Overstayed in Brazil, can I travel to Mexico/Philippines?

Tags: visas, mexico, overstaying, canadian-citizens, philippines

I'm a Canadian citizen and have overstayed my tourist visa in Brazil for the last 1.5 years. If I travel from Brazil to say Mexico or the Philippines, would I be denied by immigration officials there?

Comment: Would you be going back to Canada and from Canada to Mexio, etc. or going there straight from Brazil?

Comment: As far I know, you should be sure never overstay in Philippines if you do not have enough money for bail and good lawyer.

Comment: the latter, I would be going there straight from Brazil

Comment: Where are you? In Canada? Or are you intending to travel *from* Brazil, straight to Mexico or the Philippines? Either way, your problems are with the Brazilian state, not elsewhere.